# how can I read socket by blocking&none-multiplexing&sync mode?

Tags: c, sockets

I want to repeatedly request one specific url by maximum performance. I copied below source from github, but I think it isn't optimized for my case, so I have to tune it.
Which Option is best in my case?

1. block vs non-block
2. sync vs async
3. I think non-multiplexing is right, so I've to change select() function to the other one. Is this right?

```
char response[RESPONSE_SIZE + 1];
    char *p = response, *q;
    char *end = response + RESPONSE_SIZE;
    char *body = 0;
    enum {
        length, chunked, connection
    };
    int encoding = 0;
    int remaining = 0;

    while (1) {
        fd_set reads;
        FD_ZERO(&reads);
        FD_SET(server, &reads);
        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = 200;
        if (FD_ISSET(server, &reads)) {
            int bytes_received = SSL_read(ssl, p, end - p);
            p += bytes_received;
            *p = 0;
            if (!body && (body = strstr(response, "\r\n\r\n"))) {
                *body = 0;
                body += 4;
                printf("Received Headers:\n%s\n", response);
                q = strstr(response, "\nContent-Length: ");
                if (q) {
                    encoding = length;
                    q = strchr(q, ' ');
                    q += 1;
                    remaining = strtol(q, 0, 10);

                } else {
                    q = strstr(response, "\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked");
                    if (q) {
                        encoding = chunked;
                        remaining = 0;
                    } else {
                        encoding = connection;
                    }
                }
                printf("\nReceived Body:\n");
            }

            if (body) {
                if (encoding == length) {
                    if (p - body >= remaining) {
                        printf("%.*s", remaining, body);
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (encoding == chunked) {
                    do {
                        if (remaining == 0) {
                            if ((q = strstr(body, "\r\n"))) {
                                remaining = strtol(body, 0, 16);
                                if (!remaining) goto finish;
                                body = q + 2;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (p - body >= remaining) {
                            printf("%.*s", remaining, body);
                            body += remaining + 2;
                            remaining = 0;
                        }
                    } while (!remaining);
                }
            } //if (body)
        } //if FDSET
    } //end while(1)
    finish:

    buffer[0] = '\0';

    printf("\nClosing socket...\n");
```

Comment: Are you running multi or single threaded?  Does your code want to get on with anything else while waiting for data?  Do you want to get the data in as fast as possible?

Comment: 1. I running single thread & multiprocessing.

Comment: 2. I don't need to get anything

Comment: 3.  I want to get as fast as possible

Comment: What makes you think that the code has a relevant performance problem? Unless you have a very very low performance system or a very fast network the problem will be the network, not the code. Apart from that the code is plain wrong - for one nowhere select is called to check what FD are available. And then SSL_read should not be treated the same as read/recv since there is internal buffering (see `SSL_pending`) and it can actually require that the sockets gets writable to continue.

Comment: thx steffen. Where can I find right code? Can you recommend c network programming books?